# Translation domain on Assert\*()

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to translate entity constraint messages, based on domain?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=3)
 * @Assert\Range(
 *     min = 1,
 *     max = 999,
 *     minMessage = "foo.position.min", // I wish to insert this into foo_validator.xl
 *     maxMessage = "foo.position.max"
 * )
 */
```

How can I split my translation into more than one domain and let the framework know where to choose from?

By searching on the internet it seems that no one ever asked about and this feature seems not to be documented.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a validators translation catalog, as explained in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-constraint-messages

Comment: Hi Massimiliano. I'm aware of catalogs but it's not clear (at least to me) how to "link" them with assertion on entities. Could you provide a snippet or an explanation to that link?

Comment: Just use your string. Following your example, use "foo.position.min" as key in your catalog and whatever you want as value.

Comment: it seems not to work. I've added file loading into MyBundleExtension file loaded by DependencyInjection but ... nothings is shown. PS.: I use catalog for other messages (handled along with domain) and all works like a charm